# Allow multiple password reset tokens in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authentication

The default behaviour of Laravel (5.7)'s password reset system is to create a new token in the `password_resets` table after deleting any others for that user. This behaviour is determined in `\Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\DatabaseTokenRepository` and it doesn't seem configurable.

```
protected function deleteExisting(CanResetPasswordContract $user)
{
    return $this->getTable()->where('email', $user->getEmailForPasswordReset())->delete();
}
```

There's so much inheritance going on, I can't figure out what classes to extend so I can insert my own rules.

Is it possible to allow a certain number password resets to exist simultaneously without hacking into the Laravel core files? What classes do I need to extend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer provided did not help me override the correct class, but it did give me some ideas how to approach this. So I ended up creating three classes, all of which extend built-in classes:

**DatabaseTokenRepository**

This is where I did the overrides from [the parent class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/DatabaseTokenRepository.php) to allow my custom behaviour; keep the two most recent entries when creating a new reset token, and check multiple tokens when performing the reset.

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\DatabaseTokenRepository as DatabaseTokenRepositoryBase;

class DatabaseTokenRepository extends DatabaseTokenRepositoryBase
{
    /**
     * Create a new token record.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword  $user
     * @return string
     */
    public function create(CanResetPasswordContract $user)
    {
        $email = $user->getEmailForPasswordReset();

        $this->deleteSomeExisting($user);

        // We will create a new, random token for the user so that we can e-mail them
        // a safe link to the password reset form. Then we will insert a record in
        // the database so that we can verify the token within the actual reset.
        $token = $this->createNewToken();

        $this->getTable()->insert($this->getPayload($email, $token));

        return $token;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if a token record exists and is valid.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword  $user
     * @param  string  $token
     * @return bool
     */
    public function exists(CanResetPasswordContract $user, $token)
    {
        $records = $this->getTable()
            ->where("email", $user->getEmailForPasswordReset())
            ->get();

        foreach ($records as $record) {
            if (
               ! $this->tokenExpired($record->created_at) &&
                 $this->hasher->check($token, $record->token)
            ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Delete SOME existing reset tokens from the database.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword  $user
     * @return int
     */
    protected function deleteSomeExisting($user)
    {
        // TODO: make this configurable in app config
        $limit = 3;
        $records = $this->getTable()
            ->where("email", $user->getEmailForPasswordReset())
            ->orderBy("created_at");
        $ct = $records->count() - $limit + 1;
        return ($ct > 0) ? $records->limit($ct)->delete() : 0;
    }
}
```

**PasswordBrokerManager**

This just ensures that my custom repository class above is used. The function is copied exactly from [the parent class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBrokerManager.php), but is, of course, in a different namespace.

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBrokerManager as PasswordBrokerManagerBase;

class PasswordBrokerManager extends PasswordBrokerManagerBase
{
    /**
     * Create a token repository instance based on the given configuration.
     *
     * @param  array  $config
     * @return \Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\TokenRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected function createTokenRepository(array $config)
    {
        $key = $this->app['config']['app.key'];

        if (Str::startsWith($key, 'base64:')) {
            $key = base64_decode(substr($key, 7));
        }

        $connection = $config['connection'] ?? null;

        return new DatabaseTokenRepository(
            $this->app['db']->connection($connection),
            $this->app['hash'],
            $config['table'],
            $key,
            $config['expire']
        );
    }
}
```

**PasswordResetServiceProvider**

Again, just ensuring that the custom class is returned. Again, only the namespace changes from [the original](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordResetServiceProvider.php).

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Services\PasswordBrokerManager;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider as PasswordResetServiceProviderBase;

class PasswordResetServiceProvider extends PasswordResetServiceProviderBase
{
    /**
     * Register the password broker instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerPasswordBroker()
    {
        $this->app->singleton("auth.password", function ($app) {
            return new PasswordBrokerManager($app);
        });

        $this->app->bind("auth.password.broker", function ($app) {
            return $app->make("auth.password")->broker();
        });
    }
}
```

Finally, the application config is updated to use my provider instead of the original:

```
    // Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
```

And everything works beautifully.

Comment: Thank you very much for posting your solution! I found myself stuck in the same place whilst trying to implement username-based password resets. You got me out of a rut here, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Copied from https://www.5balloons.info/extending-passwordbroker-class-laravel-5/

**Create a `CustomPasswordResetServiceProvider` inside `App\Providers`**

You need to create a `new CustomPasswordResetServiceProvider` class which we will use to replace the Default `PasswordResetServiceProvider`

```
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Services\CustomPasswordBrokerManager; 
class CustomPasswordResetServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{
    protected $defer = true;

    public function register()
    {
        $this->registerPasswordBrokerManager();
    }

    protected function registerPasswordBrokerManager()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('auth.password', function ($app) {
            return new CustomPasswordBrokerManager($app);
        });
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return ['auth.password'];
    }
}
```

**Replace Service Provider in `app/config.php`**

```
//Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,

App\Providers\CustomPasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
```

**Create new `CustomPasswordBrokerManager` class**

Create a new class `CustomPasswordBrokerManager` and under directory `App/Services` and copy all the contents of `PasswordBrokerManager` which is located at `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBrokerManager.php`

Then modified the function resolve to return an instance of my `CustomPasswordProvider` class

```
protected function resolve($name)
{
    $config = $this->getConfig($name);
    if (is_null($config)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Password resetter [{$name}] is not defined.");
    }

    return new CustomPasswordBroker(
        $this->createTokenRepository($config),
        $this->app['auth']->createUserProvider($config['provider'])
);
}
```

**Create CustomPasswordBroker**

Finally, You can now create your new `CustomPasswordBroker` class under `App/Services` directory which extends the default `PasswordBroker` class located at `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker`

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker as BasePasswordBroker;    

class CustomPasswordBroker extends BasePasswordBroker    
{    
// override the functions that you need here    
}
```

Comment: `\Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\DatabaseTokenRepository` is the class I need to override; `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker::$tokens` is an instance of this class.