# Password reset in Laravel by email or mobile

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authentication

By default Laravel 5.5's password reset system works on email, but I need to add support for a mobile number (verify by OTP and generate a token and redirect to password reset page). I am doing all this part and I have created a mobile column on password_resets table.

But the problem is `\Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\DatabaseTokenRepository` && `\Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\TokenRepositoryInterface` ON `exist` method and it doesn't seem configurable.

```
public function exists(CanResetPasswordContract $user, $token)
{
    $record = (array) $this->getTable()->where(
        'email', $user->getEmailForPasswordReset()
    )->first();

    return $record &&
           ! $this->tokenExpired($record['created_at']) &&
             $this->hasher->check($token, $record['token']);
}
```

I need to override that method. There's so much inheritance going on.
What classes do I need to extend and how to override that method.

Comment: does your user not have an email address? or you are saying you only reference the user by a phone number on the password_resets table

Comment: I don't know if touching those classes is the way to go. I would introduce a new guard for authenticating using phone number, and override the method that sends the notification on the User model, [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passwords#password-customization)

Comment: @lagbox - yes our user has email address, but is optional. Mobile number is mandatory. So we add mobile column on password reset table

Comment: @nakov, i think this thread is helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56589029/allow-multiple-password-reset-tokens-in-laravel. i m following this, but i think i miss some things

Comment: @HasanHafizPasha you can comment on the post there and find if the guy that implemented that could help you more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to override behaviour of `\Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\DatabaseTokenRepository` methods, you will have to build your own token repository, overriding methods in the existing repository that currently just check for the 'email' column in the database. Ensure you've created a migration to add the appropriate column:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    public function up(): void
    {
        $tname = config("auth.passwords.users.table");
        Schema::table($tname, fn (Blueprint $t) => $t->string("mobile", 16));
    }

    public function down(): void
    {
        $tname = config("auth.passwords.users.table");
        Schema::table($tname, fn (Blueprint $t) => $t->dropColumn("mobile"));
    }
}
```

Then create your custom repository:

**app/Auth/DatabaseTokenRepository.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Auth;

use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\DatabaseTokenRepository as DatabaseTokenRepositoryBase;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

class DatabaseTokenRepository extends DatabaseTokenRepositoryBase;
{
    //
    // Override these methods to use mobile as well as email
    //
    public function create(CanResetPasswordContract $user)
    {
        $email = $user->getEmailForPasswordReset();
        $mobile = $user->getMobileForPasswordReset();
        $this->deleteExisting($user);
        $token = $this->createNewToken();
        $this->getTable()->insert($this->getPayload($email, $mobile, $token));
        return $token;
    }

    protected function deleteExisting(CanResetPasswordContract $user)
    {
        return $this->getTable()
            ->where("email", $user->getEmailForPasswordReset())
            ->orWhere("mobile", $user->getMobileForPasswordReset())
            ->delete();
    }

    protected function getPayload($email, $mobile, $token): array
    {
        return [
            "email" => $email,
            "mobile" => $mobile,
            "token" => $this->hasher->make($token),
            "created_at" => new Carbon(),
        ];
    }

    public function exists(CanResetPasswordContract $user, $token)
    {
        $record = (array) $this->getTable()
            ->where("email", $user->getEmailForPasswordReset())
            ->orWhere("mobile", $user->getMobileForPasswordReset())
            ->first();
        return $record &&
               ! $this->tokenExpired($record["created_at"]) &&
                 $this->hasher->check($token, $record["token"]);
    }

    public function recentlyCreatedToken(CanResetPasswordContract $user)
    {
        $record = (array) $this->getTable()
            ->where("email", $user->getEmailForPasswordReset())
            ->orWhere("mobile", $user->getMobileForPasswordReset())
            ->first();

        return $record && $this->tokenRecentlyCreated($record['created_at']);
    }
}
```

Now you will need to use this custom token repository instead of the default one. So you have to override another class.

**app/Auth/PasswordBrokerManager.php**

```php
<?php
namespace App\Auth;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBrokerManager as PasswordBrokerManagerBase;

class PasswordBrokerManager extends PasswordBrokerManagerBase
{
    protected function createTokenRepository(array $config)
    {
        $key = $this->app['config']['app.key'];
        if (Str::startsWith($key, 'base64:')) {
            $key = base64_decode(substr($key, 7));
        }
        $connection = $config['connection'] ?? null;
        // return an instance of your new repository
        // it's in the same namespace, no need to alias it
        return new DatabaseTokenRepository(
            $this->app['db']->connection($connection),
            $this->app['hash'],
            $config['table'],
            $key,
            $config['expire']
        );
    }
}
```

Now you have created a custom broker to use your custom repository. You need a new service provider to make use of it.

**app/Providers/PasswordResetServiceProvider.php**

```php
<?php
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Auth\PasswordBrokerManager;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider as PasswordResetServiceProviderBase;

class PasswordResetServiceProvider extends PasswordResetServiceProviderBase
{
    protected function registerPasswordBroker()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('auth.password', function ($app) {
            // reference your new broker
            // the rest of the method code is unchanged
            return new PasswordBrokerManager($app);
        });
        $this->app->bind('auth.password.broker', function ($app) {
            return $app->make('auth.password')->broker();
        });
    }
}
```

Next, replace default password reset service provider with the custom one in your application config:
**app/config/app.php**

```php
<?php

return [
    "providers" => [
        ...
        // Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        ...
    ],
];
```

And finally, define the `getMobileForPasswordReset()` method on your user model:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
...

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    ...
    public method getMobileForPasswordReset()
    {
        return $this->mobile;
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Been trying to figure out how exactly to do this for several days before finally finding your answer.